# How to make pizza without cheese?

Tags: pizza

Maybe I'm the only person in the world who does not like cheese ... Or maybe not ..
What are the perfect ingredients to make a pizza taste good without cheese?

Comment: inesiimoliveira, welcome to Seasoned Advice! Your question was [put on hold](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because as it’s phrased, it asks for an option - what I consider “the best” way can be totally different from what someone else does. Also, “taste good” is purely subjective, and so not a good fit for the site. Please take the [tour], browse our [help], especially [ask] to learn more about how the site works. If you [edit] your post to be [on topic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), just flag it and we will be happy to re-open it.

Comment: In the Philadelphia PA area,a dish they call a Philadelphia Tomato Pie is somewhat popular. It's basically a pizza without cheese.and crusts come in varying thickness from thin-crust pizza to focaccia bread. Here is  a link  to one recipe on Serious Eats - https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2012/02/homemade-philadelphia-tomato-pie-style-pizza-recipe.html

Comment: Some use tofu. Raw or seasoned and fried.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider making [pissaladiere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pissaladi%C3%A8re), a traditional pizza-like dish from southern France that does not have cheese.

Comment: Or you could just make pizza and leave off the cheese. You could even order it that way from your local pizza-joint. I think most should be happy to cook that special order for you since cheese is expensive.

Comment: @LorelC : I was once at a place in San Francisco years ago, and ordered a pizza without cheese.  They left off the mozzarella, but they hit everything with parmesan as soon as it came out of the oven.  I had to explain to them that it still qualified as 'cheese'.  The replacement was good (it was a sort of mushroom duxelle)

Comment: Oh, and there's also 'pizza marinara' which has no cheese : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_marinara

Answer (score 0):

A cheese as a gooey, gummy, sticky thing or just dairy cheese? There are goat chesses, there is almond cheese. I think I even saw a soy cheese.
But anyway, the bottom line is, The cheese is there for the fat. One cup of cheese is around 33 grams of fat (oh man, that's 300 kcal). But do you see yourself dumping a cup of olive oil into your dough? But the fat bring all that tastes, ingredients together and mix them while baking.
So, you can rightfully think that just making/using flavour oils you an make the same taste. And you're right. You can get the thyme, tomatoes, bacon, basil to taste great. Without of course cheese taste.

What you will end is type of Focaccia, depending on how much oil you will put in dough.

Comment: Cheese is also there for a bit of salt, especially if we're talking about hard grating cheeses.  You can either salt directly, or add something salty (capers, olives, etc.)